# File not found in external url

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a code for download image from external URL.

```
 $content = file_get_contents("http://shoecompany.in/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/new.jpg");

 $fp = fopen("assets/img/image.jpg", "w");
 fwrite($fp, $content);
 fclose($fp);
```

If image not available in external URL then I want to display error message. So what I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(@$content = file_get_contents("http://shoecompany.in/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/new.jpg") !== false){
        $content;
        //Store in the filesystem.
        $fp = fopen("assets/img/image.jpg", "w");
        fwrite($fp, $content);
        fclose($fp);
    }else{
        echo "error";
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

**[file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)**

> The function returns the read data or FALSE on failure.

So you can check your error as

```
 $content = file_get_contents("http://shoecompany.in/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/new.jpg");
if ($content === FALSE) {// check here
// handle error here... 
} else {
    $fp = fopen("assets/img/image.jpg", "w");
    if ($fp) {// fopen check here
        fwrite($fp, $content);
        fclose($fp);
    } else {
        // handle error here... 
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This function return file in case of string and on failure it returns false.
Function return Boolean FALSE but may also return a non-boolean thats why you have to use "==="

```
     $result=file_get_contents("http://shoecompany.in/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/new.jpg"); 

    if ($result === false) 
    { 
        print "Not Found. You Can handle error here";
    } 
    else 
    { 
        print " handle good case ";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using if condition

```
if(file_get_contents("http://shoecompany.in/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/new.jpg"))
{
$content = file_get_contents("http://shoecompany.in/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/new.jpg");

 $fp = fopen("assets/img/image.jpg", "w");
 fwrite($fp, $content);
 fclose($fp);
}
else
{
...Some content to display
```

}